# Load All Of My Pages At Top

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll, scrolltop

I have a website where ALL of my content pages open inside of an iframe.

One of the issue I am having, is when a visitor opens a 2nd page on my site, it opens at the same 'scroll position' as the previous page they were on.

I would like all of my pages to open at the top.

NOTE: I have spent days and hours searching on this site and other sites trying to find something that works. None of the solutions I have found have worked so far.

So... I decided to post my question and a very stripped down example of 3 pages to see if I can get some much needed help with this.

Any help or advice is appreciate.

Here is the 'index' (parent) page:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <style>
    body{margin:0;}
    .header{width:100%; height:60px; background-color:blue;}
    .header a{vertical-align:middle; line-height:60px; font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff;}
    #myiframe{width:100%; height:2000px;}
    .footer{width:100%; height:60px; background-color:blue; margin-bottom:20px;}
    .footer a{vertical-align:middle; line-height:60px; font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt; color:#ffffff;}
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="header"><a>This is the Header of the index (parent) page.</a></div>

    <iframe id="myiframe" name="myiframe" src="1stPage.html"></iframe>

    <div class="footer"><a>Footer</a></div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Here is the 1st 'content' page (including the last failed scroll code):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <style>
    body{margin:0;}
    .text{font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt;}
    .link{margin-top:1900px;}
    </style>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('html, body').scrollTop(0); 
    $(window).on('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('html, body').scrollTop(0);}, 0);
    });
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="text">This is the 1st page in iframe (..and this is 'page postition' "Top" or "0").</div>
    <div class="text">Please scroll down to the link to 2nd page.</div>

    <div class="link"><a class="text" href="2ndPage.html" target="myiframe">Click here to go to 2nd Page</a></div><br>
    <div class="text">This is the 1st page in iframe (..and this is 'page postition' "Bottom" or "X").</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

And finally... the 2nd 'content' page (also including the last failed scroll code):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>

    <style>
    body{margin:0;}
    .text{font-family:Arial; font-size:12pt;}
    .link{margin-top:1900px;}
    </style>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('html, body').scrollTop(0); 
    $(window).on('load', function() {
    setTimeout(function(){ $('html, body').scrollTop(0);}, 0);
    });
    });
    </script>

    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="text">This is the 2nd page in iframe (..and this is 'page postition' "Top" or "0").</div>
    <div class="text">Please scroll down to the link to 2nd page.</div>

    <div class="link"><a class="text" href="1stPage.html" target="myiframe">Click here to go back to the 1st Page</a></div><br>
    <div class="text">This is the 2nd page in iframe (..and this is 'page postition' "Bottom" or "X").</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in the iFrame **onload** event, as this:

```
<iframe id="myiframe" name="myiframe" src="1stPage.html" onload="scroll(0,0);"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thank you! That worked like a charm! Now I just need to figure out how to get a the pages to open with their parent pages when I share links to my pages on other sites.